# How to play downloaded movies by torrent?

Tags: torrent-client

I have downloaded the movie (chef) with help of transmission bittorrent file it was successfully downloaded.

It was in form of zip folder when exerted it is asking the password. There is small file in which they have have given link and instruction that to open the folder you need to visit link. When i visited  link they are asking to instal some foolish app.

So is there any way to open the file without password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to double-click the icon. Then, the Archive manager will open. In order to extract the actual movie, it will probably ask you for a password. The Readme file will then tell you that in order to get that password, you will need to visit a particular web site, fill in a questionnaire etc. etc. It is a scam, not worth your time.

Comment: thanks at least for answer i thought it will keep on down voted and no one will answer it